# Qiskit Aer Noise Module

Tags: noise, depolarizing-channel, qiskit

I am trying to use the following single qubit depolarizing channel (on a GHZ state for example) but the simulation histogram counts are not affected

```
noise_model = NoiseModel()
error = depolarizing_error(0.05, 1)
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
```

It should work according to their documentation
https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/tutorials/3_building_noise_models.html